# Find integer solution to formula

Tags: octave

Given two vectors of candidates:

```
x = [1 3 5];
y = [1 2 3 4];
```

I want to find which candidates satisfy an equation or formula. This is what I want to do:

```
f = x + y - 6;
solve f;
```

And then, it spits out the solutions:

```
5  1
3  3
```

If it matters, I am actually using Octave, not MatLab because I don't have a Windows machine. I know that I can do this with a for loop:

```
for i=x  
    for j=y  
        if i+j-6==0 
            disp([i j]); 
    end 
end
```

This is a trivial example. I am looking for a solution that will handle much larger examples.

Comment: Show me a question tagged Octave with a good answer. I can show you many questions tagged MatLab that are not dependent on either MatLab or Octave that have good answers. By retagging this as Octave, it is a guarantee that nobody will look at the question and it will not be answered.

Comment: @kainaw: Show me a good question tagged Octave without an answer!

Comment: If you disagree with the tag edit then you're able to put it back... There's no rule against appropriate cross-tagging.

Answer (score 0):

Solving such equations per "brute force" is generally a bad idea but here you go:

```
x = [1 3 5];
y = [1 2 3 4];

## build grid (also works for n vars)
[xx, yy] = ndgrid (x, y);

## anonymous function
f = @(x,y) abs(x + y - 6) < 16*eps 

## true?
t = f (xx, yy);

## build result
[xx(t) yy(t)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used ngrid. I've used meshgrid to get all pairs of two vectors, eg: [xx yy]=meshgrid(x,y); pairs=[xx(:) yy(:)]; For this, I think it would be best to then do pairs(sum(pairs,2)-6==0,:); Then, I would get all pairs that meet the criteria. But, the actual problems are, as I mentioned, far more complicated with up to 81 independent variables, each with up to 20 candidate values. The combined meshgrid will get very large. So, I'm seeing what the benefit of using ngrid might be.

Comment: @kainaw 20^81 = 2.4179e+105 which would be much much more than all supercomputers can calculate in a lifetime. Have you considerd this?